# "Solche" as in "such lovely songs"

Tags: grammar, adjective

In English we can say

> Such lovely songs.

Can we say in German

> Solche herrliche Lieder.

to mean the same thing? If so, should it be `herrliche` or `herrlichen`?

Comment: Remember: "such lovely songs" can both mean "solche herrlichen Lieder" and "so herrliche Lieder"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use it like this:

> Solche herrlichen Lieder.

But you can also say:

> Solche herrliche Lieder.
> Solch herrliche Lieder.

In singular you can use:

> Solch (ein) herrliches Lied. *or*
> Solches herrliche Lied.

Here's an explanation from [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu): "[Pronomen, Artikelwort und Adjektiv solcher, solche, solches](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Demonstr-solch.html)":

> Wie nach einem Artikelwort kann ein Adjektiv nach solch- schwach gebeugt werden:
>     *solche schönen Bilder*
>     *mit solchem großen Eifer*

This basically says, that you *can* use either one of them.

Here are also some details and more examples about *solch* on [duden.de](https://www.duden.de/) with some more examples: "[sol­cher, sol­che, sol­ches, solch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/solcher)".

---

As a side note: *Herrlich* is really fine here, but there are a lot of [synonyms](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herrlich) you can use too.

Comment: also see: http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html

Comment: @Takkat I did a little more research - take a look at the quote from the explanation on canoo.net. Your direction was the right one.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: much better :) However I am still confused whether after *"solche"* we have a strong, a weak, or a varying inflection in this case. I suspect that both may be possible here but I found no reference for that.

Comment: @Takkat Yeah, I didn't find anything on that either really. But as you said, you can find lots of examples for both usages.

Comment: @insertusernamehere So it seems from your canoo [link](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html#Anchor-solcher-48213) that both `Solche herrlichen Lieder.` and `Solche herrlichen Lieder.` are possible, is that correct? If so, could you please update your answer to reflect that? Thanks.

Comment: Dieser Satz kein Verb.

Comment: The one that sounds the most natural to me is not included in your list: *Solch herrliche Lieder!*

Comment: Also you could use plain _so_: _so schöne Lieder_